# Calling a parent class from a subclass

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
class experiment
{

    int xCoord = 0;
    int yCoord = 0;

    public experiment(int x, int y) {
        this.xCoord = x;
        this.yCoord = y;
    }
}

class result :experiment{
    int zCoord = 0;

    public result(int z) : base(x,y) 
    {
        this.zCoord = z;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me solve this simple problem. I'm having an error `base(x,y)` it says the name 'x' does not exists in the current context and also goes for the y.

Comment: On an additional note, your existing design is poor. `result` doesn't feel like `experiment` at all. Make `result` a member of `experiment`; called composition..

Answer (score 8):

`x` and `y` are local fields to class `experiment` they are not visible in inherited class, you may call the base constructor with default values like:

```
public result(int z) : base(0,0)
```

Also please follow [General Naming Conventions from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so the class names begins with upper case character.

EDIT:

---

It would be better if your child class has a constructor to receive parameter `x` and `y`, and the it calls the base class constructor with those values like:

```
public result(int x, int y, int z) : base(x,y) 
{
    this.zCoord = z;
}
```

Comment: tnx for the answer guys i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

There is no x,y in constructor of result class.

You pass to your constructor z but tell your base constructor to recieve x and y. Though there are no x and y at that time.

Try this:

```
public result(int z, int x, int y) : base(x,y) 
{
    this.zCoord = z;
}
```

Or set fix values (no variables):

```
public result(int z) : base(0, 0) 
{
    this.zCoord = z;
}
```